# Need to redirect to Login page on clicking browser's back button in asp.net

Tags: c#

I am building a site using ASP.Net and c#. After user logged into the application, on clicking browser's back button on any page should redirect to Login Page.

I have tried using
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

but did not work out.
I can not even disable back button.

Answer (score 3):

You have no control over the browser's Back button. The best you could do is to exclude authenticated pages from being cached (by adding proper HTTP headers) so that if the user logs out and clicks the Back button he will not be served a cached version of the previous authenticated page.

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Darin. I have also tried with the code provided by you. But its of no use.
Here issue is, even if the user logged in, if he clicks on back button he has to be redirected to Login page, irrespective of whether he logged in or not.

Comment: @DotnetDude, as I explained in my answer you could achieve this if the user logs out. If the user is still logged in, no matter whether the previous page has been cached or not, the client will send a request if it was cached and because he is still authenticated he will see the page. That's the normal behavior and you have no control over this behavior.

Comment: @Darvin, but I need to do this. This is my requirement. Is there any way to achieve this. Please help me.

Comment: @DotnetDude, nope, sorry, unless you write your own browser this is not possible with standard browsers.